# Application stuck in TCP retransmit

Tags: networking, 14.04, kernel

I am running Linux kernel 3.13 (Ubuntu 14.04) on two Virtual Machines each of which operates inside two different servers running ESXi 5.1.  There is a zeromq client-server application running between the two VMs.  After running for about 10-30 minutes, this application consistently hangs due to inability to retransmit a lost packet.

When I run the same setup over Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux 3.11), the application never fails (UPDATE : Also fails on 12.04 but takes longer)

If you notice below, "*ss*" (socket statistics) shows 1 packet lost, sk_wmem_queued of 14110 (i.e. w14110) and a high rto (120000).

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                      Local Address:Port                                          Peer Address:Port

ESTAB      0      **12350**                                       192.168.2.122:41808                                        192.168.2.172:55550    

timer:(on,16sec,10) uid:1000 ino:35042 

sk:ffff880035bcb100 <->
         skmem:(r0,rb648720,t0,tb1164800,f2274,**w14110**,o0,bl0) ts sack cubic wscale:7,7 rto:120000 rtt:7.5/3 ato:40 mss:8948 cwnd:1 ssthresh:21 send 9.5Mbps **unacked:1 retrans:1/10 lost:1** rcv_rtt:1476 rcv_space:37621
```

Since this has happened so consistently, I was able to capture the TCP log in wireshark.  I found that the packet which is lost does get retransmitted and even acknowledged by the TCP in the other OS (the sequence number is seen in the ACK), but the sender doesn't seem to understand this ACK and continues retransmitting.

MTU is 9000 on both virtual machines and througout the route.  The packets being sent are large in size.

As I said earlier, this does not happen on Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.11).  So I did a diff on the TCP config options (seen via "sysctl -a |grep tcp ") between 14.04 and 12.04 and found the following differences.

I also noticed that net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=0 in both configurations.

Left side is 3.11, right side is 3.13

```
<<net.ipv4.tcp_abc = 0
<<net.ipv4.tcp_cookie_size = 0
<<net.ipv4.tcp_dma_copybreak = 4096

14c11
<< net.ipv4.tcp_early_retrans = 2
---
>> net.ipv4.tcp_early_retrans = 3

17c14
<< net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen = 0
>> net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen = 1

20d16
<< net.ipv4.tcp_frto_response = 0
26,27c22
<< net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 16384
<< net.ipv4.tcp_max_ssthresh = 0

>> net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 4096
29,30c24,25
<< net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 16384
<< net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 94377 125837  188754

>> net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 4096
>> net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 23352 31138   46704
34a30
>> net.ipv4.tcp_notsent_lowat = -1
```

My question to the networking experts on this forum : Are there any other debugging tools or options I can install/enable to dig further into why this TCP retransmit failure is occurring so consistently ?  Are there any configuration changes which might account for this weird behaviour.

UPDATE (for those who may hit a similar problem later):  I was able to reproduce the problem on 3.11 as well and was then able to evade this problem by lowering the MTU.

A similar problem has been reported here https://serverfault.com/questions/488893/how-do-i-prevent-tcp-connection-freezes-over-an-openvpn-network.  The description given there matches what I saw :

> "At some point with the Ubuntu clients, though, the remote end starts
>   retransmitting the same TCP segment over and over (with the transmit
>   delay increasing between each retransmission). The client sends what
>   looks like a valid TCP ACK to each retransmission, but the remote end
>   still continues to transmit the same TCP segment periodically."

Maybe related article : https://blogs.kent.ac.uk/unseenit/2013/10/18/stalled-scp-and-hanging-tcp-connections/

Comment: It could be a bug. You could try installing the latest mainline kernel to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Failed on 3.14.0-031400-generic as well!  Can someone give me a couple of upvotes so I get privileges to add tags, etc ?

Comment: Latest trusty kernel from [mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) is 3.15-rc2

Comment: Could you try booting your 12.04 kernel (that works) in 14.04?

Comment: yes, will post an update after that

Comment: This is in all likelihood a zeromq bug.  I hit the problem now on 3.11 as well.

Comment: This problem was due to 4 bytes being chopped off from a TCP segment.  See https://communities.vmware.com/message/2390611#2390611

Comment: In that case, you might want to try KVM instead of ESXi.

Answer (score 2):

He we noticed the same problem: Linux 3.2 kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 worked without any problems, Linux 3.13 on Ubuntu 14.02 had the same problem.

I am not sure if this is really a bug in the kernel, to me it looks more like a problem with selective ACKs (SACK). You can workaround the problem by disabling TCP SACK with:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_sack=0
```

This worked around the problem. In our case it was happening that clients with lossy or far-away connections (e.g., different data centers, DSL lines) were no longer be able to download large files. After approx a few megabytes downloading the HTTP connection stalled. TCDump showed a lot of selective ACKS (SACKs) transmitted.

And yes, booting the 12.04 kernel in 14.04 helped, too.

I think we should open an issue in Ubuntu. I was just not sure if the problem only happens because of our network/router hardware, but it seems to generally a problem that TCP SACK is wrong.

Comment: Uwe, is this inside a Virtual machine?  I was hitting the problem with vmware and it has been observed by others.  See here for followup https://communities.vmware.com/message/2390611#2390611